# Observable<Array> Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have object array in my Angular2 application. I am using SignalR to fill array when new object arrives. Now the point is when new object arrived I had error

> cannot read property of undefined

I rode that it might be error because its working async and in html I used to take object inside object.

So now the code look like:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events">
        <div class="card overview">
            <div class="overview-content clearfix ">
                <span class="overview-title" pTooltip="{{event.name}}">{{(event | async)?.user?.name}} / {{(event | async)?.date | date:"HH:mm" }}</span>
                <span class="overview-badge "> <i class="material-icons ">{{getActivityIcon(event.activityId)}}</i>
            <button type="button" pButton (click)="selectEvent($event,event,op);" icon="fa-search"></button> 
            </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And now the error is

> NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

My object array is in component and look as below:

```
events: Observable<Event[]>;
```

I understand the error but how can I make it work now?

Comment: Add the `| async` at the end of your *ngFor

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: You can subscribe to the observable within your component and set the data in events property.

Comment: i think the `events` is not initialized in your component, show more code

Answer (score 16):

Seems you are not sure about what's the difference between `async` pipe and `subscribe`, since you are using an odd mix in your template code. Either use the async pipe or "manually" subscribe. `Async` pipe does the subscription and unsubscription for you and should not be used together with `subscribe`.

Short simple examples, first usage of async pipe:

Service:

```
getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
  return this.http.get('url')
    .map(res => res.json())
}
```

In component, we assign that observable to our observable `events$`:

```
events$ = this.myService.getEvents();
```

In HTML we use `async` pipe that does the subscription for us:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events$ | async">
  {{event.name}}
</div>
```

...Aaaand then the usage of `subscribe`:

The service method would be the same, the difference is in the component:

```
events: Event[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getEvents()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.events = data;
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events">
  {{event.name}}
</div>
```

Here I think you mixed `async` pipe with asynchronously retrieved data. So the `async` pipe is not used for asynchronously retrieved data, but to subscribe and unsubscribe to Observable.

Hope this helped and made some clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

> The AsyncPipe accepts a Promise or Observable as input and subscribes to the input automatically, eventually returning the emitted values.

[Angular.io - AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#async-pipe)