# angular 2 Service that returns a Promise

Tags: screen

i have a following ng2-Type script services that returns a Promise from a mock-server, i used the below code

the service is

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { data } from './Data';
import { Info } from './mock_server';

@Injectable()
export class TablingModalsService {
  constructor() {
  }
  getdataInfo(): Promise<data[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(Info);
  }



}
```

and the component that injects the service

```js
import { Component, ViewChild,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { data } from '../tableService/Data'

import { TablingModalsService } from '../tableService/tabling-modals.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'ms-tabling',
  templateUrl: './tabling.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabling.component.scss'],
  providers: [TablingModalsService]
})
export class TablingComponent implements OnInit{

  public information : data[];

  constructor(private gInformation:TablingModalsService){ 
  }
  
  getdataInfo():void
  {
    this.gInformation.
    getdataInfo()
    .then(information => (this.information =information).toString);
  }

  ngOnInit():void
  {
    this.getdataInfo();
  }
```

when my service returns a Promise no data seems to come through , but when i return the array like this

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { data } from './Data';
import { Info } from './mock_server';

@Injectable()
export class TablingModalsService {
  constructor() {
  }
  getdataInfo(): data[]{
    return Info;
  }
}
```

and with the call on the component being

```js
import { TablingModalsService } from '../tableService/tabling-modals.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'ms-tabling',
  templateUrl: './tabling.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabling.component.scss'],
  providers: [TablingModalsService]
})
export class TablingComponent implements OnInit{

  public information : data[];

  constructor(private gInformation:TablingModalsService){ 
  }
  
  getdataInfo():void
  {
    this.information=this.gInformation.getdataInfo();
  }

  ngOnInit():void
  {
    this.getdataInfo();
  }
```

when i do it this way it the values appear on my table , but i want to use Promises since i have read that it is a good practice to do so

Comment: I think you might need to use `.all(...)` instead of `.then(...)` if dealing w/ multiple Promises such as array

Comment: Hi Milo the .all() method is giving me an error , maybe I'm not implementing it correctly can you assist

Comment: i am returning one Promise that Promises to return an array , and I'm on Type script

Comment: You should try to implement as Observable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718440/observablearray-angular2

Comment: Thank you It worked